# Htmlselect selected index changed event

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have 2 HtmlSelect controls and i need to load second one according to first HtmlSelect's selected index. But it doesn't work, because HtmlSelect doesnt have selectedindexchanged event. What do i need to do? Any idea?

Example;

```
<!--These are my Html Select controls-->

 select runat="server" id="drpCity"></select> 
 <select runat="server" id="drpState">/select>



  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     FillCities(drpCity);
     FillStates(drpState, drpCity.SelectedValue);
  }

  public void FillCitiesHtmlSelect(HtmlSelect drpCity)
        {
           BusCity busCity = new BusCity();
           List<EntCity> lentCity = busCity.SearchAll();
           drpCity.DataValueField = EntCity.Columns.CITYCODE;
           drpCity.DataTextField = EntCity.Columns.CITYNAME;
           drpCity.DataSource = lentCity;
           drpCity.DataBind();

            drpCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("City", string.Empty));
        }

public void FillStatesHtmlSelect(HtmlSelect drpState, string cityCode)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityCode))
       {
          BusState busState = new BusState();
          List<EntState> lentEmsState = busState.Search(cityCode);
          drpState.DataValueField = EntState.Columns.STATECODE;
          drpState.DataTextField = EntState.Columns.STATENAME;
          drpState.DataSource = lentState;
          drpState.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
          drpState.Items.Clear();
        }
           drpState.Items.Insert(0, "State", string.Empty));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an approach, though i have not implemented it. If you can call a javascript function from your one select control to check for a non-default value and if the condition meets, load the second select html.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i am not good at javascript. if you have an exaple code, then i can apply it.I just googled for this,but couldnt find related example.

Answer (score 0):

Html select control does not have 'selectedindexchanged' event,instead it have client side event 'onchange'.Also you can't call a serverside from html select control.To invoke function writen inside c# code page(serverside) you need to use webservice.Define your c# function as webmethord and call function using a webservice in 'onchange' event of html select control.